# Running a 03 and 10 Exchange server and would like to take 03 offline but 10 breaks when I do so

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, exchange-2003

I'm sort of a green network admin, I've been doing this for about 3 years but because of my lack of experience I really havent had a chance to do "everything" yet. Most big projects are 100% new to me, for example, migrating our exchange server from 2003 to 2010. We did this last January, without issue. I've moved over all mailboxes and as of now there is no one actually using the 2003 exchange server. Since 2010 was up and running, I assumed I could just turn off  2003 and be done with it. Wrong. When I do that it breaks email for our agency. I assume it has something to do with the connectors in place on either box, but I'm not sure what it needs to be changed for 2010 to operate alone. I'm not sure what specifically my problem is, but I assume it has something to do with the connectors on 2010. Does anyone know off the top of their head what my issue is? How do i get 2010 to work alone without 2003?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found that actually in-installing exchange from the original server rather than just "turning it off" helped as it brought up a bunch of warnings during the in-install process, but that was 2007 not 2003

Comment: I'm wondering if uninstalling it will allow 2010 to work correctly, but I'm afraid of killing the entire agency's email if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few concepts and checklists you should visit when transitioning from 2003 to 2010. Fortunately, Microsoft created a tool to cover everything that you may encounter. Check it out here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/exdeploy2010/default.aspx#Index - You're going to want to run the On-Premises wizard and 2003 to 2010 upgrade. In particular, you are going to want to pay attention to the "Post-installation tasks". If you run into further problems after reviewing and trying some of the tasks in the guide, be sure to include error messages, and the procedure you take to reproduce the problem(s). Good luck!

Comment: I'm going through this checklist, a lot of which I know I did when I migrated. I went through the post installation tasks and found some policy stuff that needed to be upgraded from LADP to OPATH filters, not sure what all that did but it seemed to upgrade correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the DNS records to point to the new 2010 mail server?

Comment: I had an entry for the old mail server in the forward lookup zone which I went ahead and deleted. I created a new host (a) record for the new mail server. I think the MX record is controlled by our parent agency, so if that needs to double checked I'll have to contact someone else.

Comment: You can check the MX record using command prompt. Type nslookup then change the type using "set type=mx" then type in your domain. The results should display your MX records.

Comment: I don't see what exactly I'm supposed to be looking for from the results. When I run this command on my mail server, I get


C:\Users\administrator.OCC>nslookup
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  10.10.10.16

> set type=mx
> conservation.ok.gov
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  10.10.10.16

conservation.ok.gov
        primary name server = occsrv7.occ.local
        responsible mail addr = hostmaster.occ.local
        serial  = 3
        refresh = 900 (15 mins)
        retry   = 600 (10 mins)
        expire  = 86400 (1 day)
        default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

Comment: Just another way to verify that your configuration is correct. So all your emails will first arrive at interceptor.oda.state.ok.us which has an IP of 204.87.123.90

Comment: That is our spam filter that we share with another agency. I'm wondering if the spam filter is stripping the email....It never did before...

Comment: Rowell, what did I do wrong not to see the IP you just pulled? Just for my own reference.

Comment: I ran the same command you did: 

nslookup
> set type=mx
> conservation.ok.gov

Non-authoritative answer:
conservation.ok.gov     MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = int
te.ok.us
conservation.ok.gov     MX preference = 100, mail exchanger = ma
.us
conservation.ok.gov     MX preference = 100, mail exchanger = ma
ok.gov

interceptor.oda.state.ok.us     internet address = 204.87.123.90
mail.okcc.state.ok.us   internet address = 204.87.70.3
mail.conservation.ok.gov        internet address = 204.87.70.3